# If I upgrade a domain joined Windows 7 machine to 8.1 will it still be joined to the domain?

Tags: windows-7, windows-domain, windows-8.1-upgrade

I am an admin on the machine but I am not a domain admin.

Will it allow me to login via a domain login after upgrade rather than forcing me to use a windows live account?

Comment: Of course it will be provided the domain supports Windows 8.1; without any information; hard to provided a precise yeah or nay

Comment: @Ramhound seems like a reasonable answer, you could post it as one and provide more detail about the 'of course' part (why is it so obvious, etc)

Comment: I don't answer vague questions.  There are to many questions I have, you know the major one, and you didn't respond to it.

Comment: @Ramhound It's not vague, it's just a general question. The answer could be either: *"the system is designed to maintain your domain joined status if possible (list of conditions that would make it not possible)"*, or: *"no, never, it will always need to be manually joined to the domain again"*.

Comment: **I ask specifically for information on the domain controller.**  If the domain controller does not support Windows 8.1 nodes then it doesn't matter, if a node running a previous version of Windows when upgraded to Windows 8.1, if it will connect to the domain or not.